# 3ware 9650SE-24M8 INOPERABLE data recovery

Tags: raid, 3ware, raid6

I have a raid6 array with 16 hdds. Two harddrives had failed (device error), but when I went to replace them, I pulled out one wrong disk!

Now the raid array is INOPERABLE. Is there any way to recover the data? I don't care about the last 10 seconds of writes done at the broken disks, while the wrong disk was out.

Is there any way to read data using the disk I accidentally pulled out?

*Edit: The broken disks has actually showed up as being part of a different raid array (u1 and u2) - and both report the other 15 disks are missing. Can I reintroduce them into the 'proper' raid?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to the extremely helpful support people as AMCC, this was rectified by hard-coding a new configuration on the controller!

I'm happy to report that 99% of data got saved!